# How to compare two dataframes and return a column with difference?

Tags: python, pandas

I am preparing a dataframe to store the change in employee skills.

I want to compare two tables with these labels: 'Employee Name', 'Skill Name', 'Year' and 'Score'. Some of employees were employed in and some of skills were added in the second year. I want to check if an employee or skill is missing within both dataframes and fill gaps so that the dataframes' shape is the same.

```py
dataset = dataset[['Employee Name', 'Skill Name', 'Year', 'Score']]

min_y = dataset['Year'].min()
max_y = dataset['Year'].max()

ds1 = ds1.sort_values(['Employee Name', 'Skill Name'], ascending=[True, False])
ds2 = ds2.sort_values(['Employee Name', 'Skill Name'], ascending=[True, False])

ds1 = dataset[dataset['Year']==min_y].reset_index().drop(['index'], axis=1).drop(['Year'], axis=1)
ds2 = dataset[dataset['Year']==max_y].reset_index().drop(['index'], axis=1).drop(['Year'], axis=1)

dsBool = (ds1 != ds2).stack()
dsdiff = pd.concat([ds1.stack()[dsBool], ds2.stack()[dsBool]], axis=1)
dsdiff.columns=["Old", "New"]
```

Currently comparing these two tables causes an error because of the difference in shape between the two DataFrames:
Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Comment: What is `df1.index` and `ds2.index` before you try the comparison? Do they match?

Comment: It occurs this error: Lengths must match to compare

Comment: Yes but can you post what `ds1.index` and `ds1.index` are before the comparison, i.e. just before `dsBool = (ds1 != ds2).stack()`

Comment: ```python
Int64Index([567,  14, 505, 504,  13,  12, 566,  11, 503,  10,
            ...
            806, 740, 739, 738, 737, 807, 736, 646, 497, 805],
           dtype='int64', length=825)

Int64Index([ 778,   13,  539,   12,   11,   10,  538,  954,  956,  955,
            ...
            1242, 1241, 1244, 1240, 1239, 1123,  951,  950, 1238,  768],
           dtype='int64', length=1289)

```

Comment: Would be easier to asnwer if you provide a sample of both dataframes.

Comment: ds1:
Employee Name Skill Name Score
567 Emp1 Simulation - Circuit (PSpice, etc.) 2
14 Emp1 Short Circuit Design, Standards & Test 0
505 Emp1 Sensing Technologies - Current 1
504 Emp1 Requirements Tracking 1
13 Emp1 Product/System Architecture - Sampled Data Sys... 0

ds2:
 Employee Name Skill Name Score
778 Emp2 Simulation - Circuit (Simplorer, PSpice, etc.) 2
13 Emp2 Short Circuit Design, Standards & Test 0
539 Emp2 Sensing Technologies - Current 1
12 Emp2 Requirements Tracking 0

I do not know how to display it as table in comment :(

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure that both dataframes are indexed the same before comparison:

```
ds1 = dataset[dataset['Year']==min_y].drop(['Year'], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
ds2 = dataset[dataset['Year']==max_y].drop(['Year'], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then perform your comparison:

```
dsBool = (ds1 != ds2).stack()
```

**Edit:**

Actually, I think you're original post may have code in the wrong order. Try the following:

```
dataset = dataset[['Employee Name', 'Skill Name', 'Year', 'Score']]

dataset.sort_values(['Employee Name', 'Skill Name'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)

ds1 = dataset[dataset['Year'] == dataset['Year'].min()].drop(['Year'], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
ds2 = dataset[dataset['Year'] == dataset['Year'].max()].drop(['Year'], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

dsBool = (ds1 != ds2).stack()
dsdiff = pd.concat([ds1.stack()[dsBool], ds2.stack()[dsBool]], axis=1)
dsdiff.columns=["Old", "New"]
```

Comment: It occurs and error: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Comment: @psowa001 Your column names must not match so. What is the output of `ds1.columns` and `ds2.columns`?

Comment: ds1.columns:
Index(['Employee Name', 'Skill Name', 'Score'], dtype='object')
ds2.columns:
Index(['Employee Name', 'Skill Name', 'Score'], dtype='object')

Answer (score 0):

As understood, shape error is due to addition of new employees and updating the skills of existing employees. To find out the missing values, you can join these data-frames and then delete the entries that are repeating. This way, the only entries left would be the ones that are different in both the data-frames.

```
temp = pd.concat((ds1, ds2), axis = 0)
temp = temp.drop_duplicates(subset = 'Employee Name', keep = False, inplace = True)
# keep = False ensures that all repeating entries are considered duplicates
```

The temp data-frame now consists of all the entries which are different in the initial 2 data-frames. They can be searched and edited in those data-frames at the end of which their shape would match.

Comment: Output for this code is dataframe with just one 'Score' column so I can not calculate difference between years

Comment: Try deleting duplicates by only comparing employee name. I'v edited the code for it.

Comment: I used our code, output temp.columns for this is : Index(['Employee Name', 'Skill Name', 'Score'], dtype='object')